# Check if mysql query found results PHP

Tags: php

How do you check if it actually found results in a mysql query in php

for eg

```
$usersearch=mysql_query("Select * FROM users WHERE username=$Searchboxinput");
if($usersearch==successfull){
//What happens when successfull
}
else{
//what happens when unsuccessfull
}
```

so if it found a user matching $searchboxinput it will do something and vice vera

Comment: You do NOT want to write new code using the old, deprecated, "mysql_query()" API.  You want to use the newer [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or PDO interfaces.  In any case, you can check the result for num rows > 0.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
if(mysql_num_rows($usersearch) > 0){
//What happens when successfull
}
else{
//what happens when unsuccessfull
}
```

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

You may also be open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174).

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
//mysql_query returns resource when successful 
if(mysql_num_rows($usersearch) > 0 ) {...}
else {...}
```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

**Note:** Mysql_* extensions are deprecated. Try using PDO or Mysqli extensions instead.

Answer (score 0):

check like this

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($usersearch);


if($count)>0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$usersearch` will contain a pointer to a query result set if the query is able to execute (regardless of whether there was a match), or if the query actually fails for some reason, it would hold a value of `false`.

As such, you need to check against the result set to see if there are actually any records returned.  Oftentimes this is simply done using `mysql_num_rows()`.  here is an example:

```
$usersearch=mysql_query("Select * FROM users WHERE username=$Searchboxinput");
if(false === $usersearch){
    // there was a problem running the query
    echo mysql_error();
} else if (mysql_num_rows($usersearch) === 0) {
    // no results were found
} else {
    //  you have at least one record returned
}
```

I would also suggest you learn to use `mysqli` or `PDO` as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.